# How do I force a specific child element to resize on overflow?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 tags inside of a div, and I'd like to force a particular element of those three to shrink when the parent div does and the other 2 to remain visible and not shrink (specifically, I'd like to make the number overflow with an ellipsis and allow the icon and the currency label to always be visible. Is there any elegant way to do this? Thanks!

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ugbpbj1v/

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="outer-box">
    <span class="inner-box">6,039,460.00</span>
    <div class="currency-label">USD</div>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-up icon"></i>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outer-box {
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-box {
    display: inline;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.currency-label {
    display: inline;
    }

.icon {
    display: inline;
}
```

Change the max-width of the div to simulate the kind of resizing I'm refering to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to the rescue! Note that `overflow: hidden` should be applied to the element with `text-overflow` for it to work.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darrylyeo/5z556x3g/)

```css
.outer-box {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 14px;
}
.outer-box > * {
    flex: 0 auto;
}
.inner-box {
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.currency-label {
    display: inline;
}

.icon {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="outer-box">
    <span class="inner-box">6,039,460.00</span>
    <div class="currency-label">USD</div>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-up icon"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, works great! I have an additional wrinkle though that I just realized. In the case of a very small parent div, I'd like to prioritize the icon over the currency label over the number. Is it possible to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! If the parent container is proportional to the viewport width than you use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), but otherwise I can think of no good way to conditionally hide the currency label.